# How does the UYVY (YUV 4:2:2, Y422, UYNV, HDYC) colour system handle odd pixel counts?

Tags: video-processing, video-encoding, yuv, color-space, subsampling

According to a [reference](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#UYVY) that I've been reading, some planar YUV formats (e.g. UYVY) use macropixels which contain data for multiple pixels - specifically, in the case of UYVY, luma values per pixel and U and V samples for every other horizontal pixel.

What I don't see described is what value should be used for video when the dimensions are not divisible by 2. For example, if a frame's width in pixels is odd, should the last macropixel on each line wrap onto the next line, or should the second Y value be assumed to be ignored during decoding? Is there a standard for what that Y value should be set to (e.g. zero)?

If the macropixels *do* wrap, then what should be the case for the final macropixel in frame sizes with an odd pixel count, such as 51x51?

Answer (score 2):

I asked about this on `#ffmpeg` on Freenode IRC, and a kind person named iive gave me some answers.

Each line is treated separately, so there's no wrapping of values in a macropixel from one line to the next. In the case of an odd frame width, the Y value from the last pixel is duplicated. So, if you've got a pixel with YUV values of `[123, 45, 67]` at the end of a line, the UYVY macropixel would have values of `[45, 123, 67, 123]`.

There may also be padding at the end of each line's data, in order to align each frame line to a boundary so that SIMD instructions only need to operate on aligned data. This depends on the exact format you're using.